# SQL JOIN of 2 tables with 2 sums

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have TABLE1 that I am selecting a subset of product codes.
I have TABLE2 that has daily instances of those products I want to count that meet condition X for ColumnA. I also want to count instances of those same products that meet condition Y for ColumnA.

I thought a simple left join would do it so I can see ALL of the subset from TABLE1 and only counts from TABLE2, BUT whenever I put a date filter or place the condition statements, it behaves as an inner join.

Ideally, my output would look like

| Date | Product | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1 | AAA | 5 | 10 |
| 1/1 | BBB | 0 | 0 |
| 1/1 | CCC | 3 | 5 |
| 1/1 | DDD | 0 | 0 |
| 1/1 | EEE | 0 | 0 |

I need to do this in 1 statement since I can't create a table to hold them.
What I have been trying (unsuccessfully) is I do a Left Join on Table1 to Table2.
I select the date I want, product code, and count of my product codes for condition X.
In my WHERE, I am asking for the Date from Table2, and I bring my subset of products in via a lengthy IN statement.

```
SELECT ProductDate, ProductCode, COUNT(ProductCode)
FROM TABLE1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2  on ProductCode
WHERE TABLE2.DATE='1/1' AND TABLE1.Product IN('AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD','EEE')
```

However, my output is that of an INNER JOIN.

| Date | Product | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1 | AAA | 5 | 10 |
| 1/1 | CCC | 3 | 5 |

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Move the predicate `TABLE2.DATE='1/1'` from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause.

Comment: `"I need to do this in 1 statement since I can't create a table to hold them."` Always the best plan. Avoid temp tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t2.ProductDate, t1.ProductCode
    , SUM(CASE WHEN t2.ColumnA = X THEN 1 END) As X
    , SUM(CASE WHEN t2.ColumnA = Y THEN 1 END) As Y
FROM TABLE1 t1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON t1.ProductCode=t2.ProductCode
    AND t2.DATE='1/1'
WHERE t1.ProductCode IN('AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD','EEE')
GROUP BY t1.ProductCode, t2.ProductDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing a left join, it's possible that TABLE2.DATE and TABLE2.ProductCode will be null so you need to include that possibility in your WHERE clause. You will also need to update the SUM arguments as shown:

```
SELECT TABLE1.Date, TABLE1.ProductCode
, SUM(CASE WHEN TABLE2.ProductCode IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS X
FROM TABLE1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2  on TABLE1.ProductCode = TABLE2.PRODUCT
WHERE 
(TABLE2.DATE='1/1' OR TABLE2.ProductCode IS NULL)
AND TABLE1.ProductCode IN ('AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD','EEE')
GROUP BY TABLE1.Date, TABLE1.ProductCode
```